# Using stdout.flush() in the middle of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I have GUI that I created using PyQt5, I'm trying to print the output of the function to the QtextEdit, using the following code:

```
class MyStream(QObject):
   textWritten = pyqtSignal(str)    

   def write(self, text):
      self.textWritten.emit(str(text))
```

and then

```
sys.stdout = MyStream(textWritten = self.myfunction)
```

The problem with this is it waits for the entire function to execute before printing to the gui. So within the function instead of print function I tried using sys.stdout.write("some string") followed by sys.stdout.flush(). The problem with this is, even though it print immediately to the gui the function stops executing after the flush() statement. Could someone please point out my error or point me to a better way to handle this. Thank you!

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: The code is really long, the error it gives me is that MyStream() has no attribute flush. Does that help ?